# How to make new Zurb Foundation support for IE 7+?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I recently build an responsive website. I use [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) because some advice and article its the best solution for make responsive website more efficient. But the problem, the new version of Foundation don't support for IE 7+, as you can see [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/support.html), but I want my website support for all of IE version. Some suggest advice to use old Foundation (i.e. vers 3). But I think the newest version is the best.

My question, any solution to make new Foundation (vers. 4) support for IE?
I need the advice because I'm stack here. Thank you

Comment: Do you see that this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zurbchris/5068210) provide a grid for IE8? It's linked in their documents.

Comment: @Pigueiras: yes, I try before but Its use for IE 8 but not useful for IE 7 or lower. So, I'm really stack here.

Comment: Are you very advanced with your project? In my opinion, you shouldn't have used a CSS framework that doesn't support IE7, if that was one of your requirements. There are some other frameworks that support IE7 like Twitter Bootstrap or Skeleton. Anyway, why is it really necessary IE7 support for your site? [There aren't many people with that browser in the world](http://theie7countdown.com/).

Comment: [And this one is funny](http://theie10countdown.com/)

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard using respond.js makes Foundation 4 work pretty well in IE8.  Not sure about 7, but technically respond.js supports IE6-8. Modernizr might help too.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with IE7 and IE8 is that they don't have built in support for media queries.

There are some options which **may** help you though, [cross-browser polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) that add media query support to old browsers.

The two most popular are [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) and [css3-mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) . I've had success with both.

In the head of your page, you test the browser and load one of these scripts if necessary.

Ways I've done this in the past are either with conditional comments:

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<script src="path-to/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

or by using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com)

```
Modernizr.load([
{
// The test: does the browser understand Media Queries?
test : Modernizr.mq('only all'),
// If not, load the respond.js file
nope : '/js/respond.js'
}
]);
```

Both methods are easy enough to try, and even if though don't help you this specific case, you'll probably get the opportunity to try them again on another site.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this http://justthisguy.co.uk/responsive-sass-and-ie/ that looks at using bootstrap and having sass generate an ie7 stylesheet that defaults to the desktop view. I'm going to work on a foundation version of it at some point. It results in some duplication of css rules but something like https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss could be used to remove that duplication